# Printing array of char pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers, file-handling, char-pointer

I am trying to read two lines from a file using array of pointers. However, I am not getting anything on screen. I have tried searching online, but could not solve the problem. Here is my code that I have written using Netbeans on mac.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {


            FILE *fp;
        char *points[50];
            char c;
        int i=0; 

        fp=fopen("/Users/shubhamsharma/Desktop/data.txt","r");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
                printf("Reached here");
            fprintf(stderr," Could not open the File!");
            exit(1);
        }
            c=getc(fp);
        while(c!=EOF)
               {
                *points[i]=c;
                c=getc(fp);
                i++;
           } 

        for(int i=0;*points[i]!='\0';i++)
        {
                char d=*points[i];

            printf("%c",d);
                if(*(points[i+1])==',')
                {
                    i=i+1;
                }
        }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: personally I'd use a debugger

Comment: `char *points[50];
            char c;` --> `char points[50] ={0};
            int c;`

Comment: I have tried that without using pointers and that worked. However, I am learning pointers. Therefore, I must have pointers.

Comment: @Sankalps that you want to learn about pointers is one thing. However that isn't an appropriate way of using them.

Comment: `char *p = &points[0];` then `*points[i];i++;` replace with `*p++`

Comment: I have just started learning c. Please tell me what is wrong with my usage of pointers so that I will stop doing that in future.

Comment: pointer pointing to Object(this case `char`, e.g `char c;char *cp = &c;`)  is required.

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to dynamically allocate memory and assign it to the 2 pointers standing for the two lines, or perhaps to an array of pointers pointing to a sequence of words. You declare pointers alright, but the do not point at anything because you didn't use malloc.

Comment: Also, you’re not checking whether you overflow your buffer or how many characters you read.

Comment: you use dereference  without pointer set to value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *points[50];
```

Is not what you want, this is an array of 50 pointers to `char`.

If you want an array of pointers to `char[50]` you need:

```
char (*points)[50];
points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);
```

Also note that `fgets` is prefered to get a line from a file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char (*points)[50];

    points = malloc(sizeof(*points) * 2);
    if (points == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fp = fopen("/Users/shubhamsharma/Desktop/data.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fgets(points[0], sizeof(*points), fp);
    fgets(points[1], sizeof(*points), fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s", points[0]);
    printf("%s", points[1]);
    free(points);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks much, That worked perfectly. why we used malloc though?

Comment: So, everytime we create pointers we have to allocate them in the memory using malloc, as they don't point to anything. Am I correct?

Comment: You're right, note that in this case (when you know how many items before-hand) you don't need an array of pointers to `char`, `char points[2][50];` is enough.